# What's the difference between HttpContext.Current.Session and HttpContext.Current.Items?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose

I know that the data stored in Session is alive until the user closes the browser while the data stored in Items is alive until the request/response is processed.

I also know that if I call Session.Abandon() it will make the Session behave like Items.

I made some tests where I've put an Entity Framework DbContext (to keep the connection to the sql server alive) in Session in the first case and in the second case in Items, so if it does no exist I instantiate it otherwise I get it from one of these storages.

I saw that the queries on the context from the Session are faster than the queries on context from the Items.

It's weird because I inspected the Dispose() method from the context in both cases and it's called as expected - at the end of Session or Items.

Now, if I'm calling Session.Abandon() then the queries are the same for both cases in terms of execution speed.

What is happening here, why am I facing this situation?

Comment: So your actual question has nothing to do with the question title.. Your actual question is "Why is database access from the request cache slower than database access from the session cache?" to which the answer is another question, "Why on earth are you accessing the database from either of those things?"

Comment: While my question is not isolated to the 2 types of storage mentioned it is related to their effect on the EntityFramework context. I'm holding the reference to the context in cache so that I keep the connection open in a ResourceProvider which is not static and would dispose the context otherwise.

Comment: I could reformulate my question to "Why is the Session so special from Items to an extent that it affects the performance of db access?".

Comment: A context should only live through one request, and you should have a really good reason to use the `HttpContext.xx` to serve it within that unit of work.

Comment: @scheien correct - that's the purpose of storing it into Items which lives only through one request, but somehow when it's prolonged (not good, I know) in a Session (without calling Abandon()) the queries are faster.

Comment: That's probably because the query is cached (warm query). Read more about cold vs warm queries [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the context is already there, and the query has been executed already, it is probably cached, which in turn would improve execution time.

You should read about cold vs warm queries, and what impact it can have on your application.

[Cold vs warm queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#2)

> The very first time any query is made against a given model, the
>   Entity Framework does a lot of work behind the scenes to load and
>   validate the model. We frequently refer to this first query as a
>   "cold" query.  Further queries against an already loaded model are
>   known as "warm" queries, and are much faster.